# No such file or directory open syscall error

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I created a folder "progfiles" on the desktop and then created an empty document named "newfile.txt" in it. After that I wrote a program to open and read write newfile.txt but on running error occured on checking errno it gave error "no such file or directory", my part of the program is:

```
  fdr = open("Desktop/progfiles/newfile.txt",O_RDONLY,0666);

  if(fdr == -1)
  {
      printf("Error:Failed to open\n");
      perror("open:");
  }
```

Why is it? What is the mistake I've made.

Comment: you should first know the difference between absolute path and relative path

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the full file path or a relative path to `open()`

```
int fdr=open("/home/<User>/Desktop/progfiles/newfile.txt",O_RDONLY,0666);
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, you either need to include the full file path OR make sure that your executable is in the right folder regarding the location of your file, as for your example if the path you are giving to `open()` is `"Desktop/progfiles/newfile.txt"` you want to make sure that your executable is located on the parent folder of `Desktop`.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu on virtualbox and my user name is "saud". So i think the pathname will be "home/saud/Desktop/progfiles/newfile.txt". Am i write or wrong?

Comment: Open a terminal. Navigate to the where the file is. Use the command `pwd` to get the current directory,  where the file is located. Now use that path and the file name.

Comment: Yes `pwd` is the way to go if you want to be sure. But your guess seems right.